# How to call Excel macro in xlam file from Outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to call a macro from Outlook.

I can do it with an Excel .xlsm file.

How can I call a macro in an addin .xlam file?

Example for .xlsm

```vb
Sub trans_outlook()
    Dim xlApp As Object, xlWkb As Object
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = False ' can be False if you do not wont see reaction, byt make sure is not fail
    Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xyz.xlsm")
    xlApp.Run "xyz.xlsm!Test"
    xlWkb.Close savechanges:=False
    xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Tools -> References. Find `Microsoft Excel 14.0 Data Objects Library` in the list, and check the box next to it. Click OK

```
 Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
 Dim ExWbk As Workbook
 Set ExApp = New Excel.Application
 Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Folder\Folder\File.xls")
 ExApp.Visible = True

 ExWbk.Application.Run "ModuleName.YourMacro"

 ExWbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: Why do you open file .xls? It is file .xlam (addin). In this file, macro A. I want to call macro A from outlook.